# No database selected?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to insert some values to my database using PDO but it just says "No database selected".

```
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "aura";
$user = "root";
$pass = "somepassword";

try {
$DB = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
$DB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$DB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}

$SignUp = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `name`, `email`, `rank`, `lvl`, `xp`, `money`, `age`, `reg_ip`, `last_ip`, `created`, `last_online`, `last_action`, `online`)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");

    $SignUp->bindValue(1, $username);
    $SignUp->bindValue(2, $password);
    $SignUp->bindValue(3, $name);
    $SignUp->bindValue(4, $email);
    $SignUp->bindValue(5, '1');
    $SignUp->bindValue(6, '1');
    $SignUp->bindValue(7, '1');
    $SignUp->bindValue(8, '100');
    $SignUp->bindValue(9, NULL);
    $SignUp->bindValue(10, $ip);
    $SignUp->bindValue(11, $ip);
    $SignUp->bindValue(12, $time);
    $SignUp->bindValue(13, $time);
    $SignUp->bindValue(14, $time);
    $SignUp->bindValue(15, $online);

    try{
    $SignUp->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
    }
```

I do not know why I get this error because I have connected successfully to the database and as you can see I have specified a database.

Comment: It looks like your `$DB = new PDO(...)` line failed. You should try adding the error mode to your options array in that line to see if it throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

It looks ok, but you may have issues with the first try catch and your not killing and possible confusing the insert with the errors from the first. 
Also wrap the whole statements in the try catch blocks also using `$e->__toString()` its going to give you a full stack trace, often that makes it easyier to trace where the error is.

Try this, I couldn't tell you if the following changes will fix the issue but might make it more clearer.

```
<?php 
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$dbname = "aura";
$user = "root";
$pass = "somepassword";

try {
    $DB = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbname, $user, $pass, array(
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
    );

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die('<pre>'.$e->__toString().'</pre>');
}


try{
    $SignUp = $DB->prepare("
    INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, 
                         `name`, `email`, `rank`, 
                         `lvl`, `xp`, `money`, 
                         `age`, `reg_ip`, `last_ip`, 
                         `created`, `last_online`, 
                         `last_action`, `online`)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");

    $SignUp->bindValue(1, $username);
    $SignUp->bindValue(2, $password);
    $SignUp->bindValue(3, $name);
    $SignUp->bindValue(4, $email);
    $SignUp->bindValue(5, '1');
    $SignUp->bindValue(6, '1');
    $SignUp->bindValue(7, '1');
    $SignUp->bindValue(8, '100');
    $SignUp->bindValue(9, NULL);
    $SignUp->bindValue(10, $ip);
    $SignUp->bindValue(11, $ip);
    $SignUp->bindValue(12, $time);
    $SignUp->bindValue(13, $time);
    $SignUp->bindValue(14, $time);
    $SignUp->bindValue(15, $online);
    $SignUp->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die('<pre>'.$e->__toString().'</pre>');
}
?>
```

Comment: You can also remove the `catch` blocks to get an unhandled exception including the stack trace.

Comment: oop, perils of a quick copy and paste, cheers, yeah I know but I wouldn't want to advise as to not use them, the idea was to get more info about what's going on. Suppose there's also `$e->getTrace()` too